# BlackBox-Testing with JUnit. How to create different test cases for this specific code?

Tags: java, junit

Today in school we got a task in which we should create a JUnit test with different types of test cases.

The actual code of the program for the test:

```
public static int[] remove(LinkedList<Integer> list) {
    if (list == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if (list.size() == 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    LinkedList<Integer> copy = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Integer i : list) {
        copy.add(i);
    }

    Collections.sort(copy);

    int lowest = copy.getFirst();
    int highest = copy.getLast();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) == lowest || list.get(i) == highest) {
            list.remove(i--);
        }
    }

    int[] arr = new int[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        arr[i] = list.get(i);
    }

    return arr;
```

This program should remove the lowest and highest integer of the LinkedList.
The task is to program 2 cases where the program works "normally" and to create 2 cases where the program reaches its limits.

I've tried the following:

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

@Before
public void before() {
    list.clear();
}


@Test
public void testRemoveNormal1() {
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    int[] resultArray = { 2, 3 };
    assertEquals(resultArray, Functionality.remove(list));
}

@Test
public void testRemoveNormal1() {
    list.add(5);
    list.add(6);
    list.add(7);
    int[] resultArray = { 6 };
    assertEquals(resultArray, Functionality.remove(list));
}

@Test
public void testRemoveBorderCase1() {
    list.add(1);
    int[] resultArray = {};
    assertEquals(resultArray, Functionality.remove(list));
}

@Test
public void testRemoveBorderCase2() {
    list.add(2);
    list.add(2);
    int[] resultArray = {};
    assertEquals(resultArray, Functionality.remove(list));
}
```

For all of these four test, I get an AssertionError, but I have no clue why exactly. Technically, this should work.

I have already tried the remove method in a main with exactly the same integer values as in the tests. But still the tests fail.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

`assertEquals(...)` will try to compare instances using `equals(...)` method, but arrays do not have specific `equals` implementation. This means that the default implementation from `Object` will be used, which is the same as comparing instances via `==` operator.

In order to properly compare contents of two arrays, `assertArrayEquals(...)` should be used instead.